# Error "No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups" getting in creating new java maven project

Tags: java, xml, maven

I am trying to create a new java maven project in Netbeans 8.2 . I am following the below steps:

[image]

[image]

Logs:

```
Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.3.1
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.0/maven-site-plugin-3.0.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.0
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.0/maven-release-plugin-2.0.pom
Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.0
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 4.914s
Finished at: Sat Feb 08 10:44:37 BDT 2020
Final Memory: 7M/119M
```

But I am getting this error.

```
No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/sultan/.m2/repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Answer (score 17):

same issue I got, and similarly on Netbeans 8.2:

Within the Netbeans installation, this settings update worked for me:

Goto `Netbeans installation folder > java > maven > conf`

for me it was `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\conf`, and here I updated the `settings.xml` file using administrative privilege.

as http repo link will not work now, just I created an valid https mirror for central repo that is pre-built with IDE which cannot be changed.

Add this inside mirrors tag of `settings.xml`

```
<mirror>
      <id>mirror1</id>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      <name>mirror1</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
</mirror>
```

after this restart Netbeans IDE, and central repository will be overridden with the mirror we specified `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/`.

Comment: it did it for me on netbeans 8.2 running on macOS, thanks @Karthik

Comment: Great Man! It worked also for me after many hours of trying to find a solution to this horrible issue! Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: Why does this solve the issue? / How is this solution related to the error message?

Answer (score 1):

The part of output says `ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required`, so therefore it cannot make proper request to the `http` endpoint.

Try changing the URLs to the maven central repository in your maven settings.
The globals are in: `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml`
And user settings in: `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`
There's possibility that you're using maven which comes with Netbeans installation, then you'd need to search for that setting file in netbeans installation folder. Try going to Tools/Options/Maven on netbeans interface - there should be info about the location currently used maven directory.

Search the `repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` (or the whole URL from your logs) through those files and change the `http` to `https`.
Just to add, the error contains the `http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` URL - prehaps you can search for it in that `settings.xml` files and change `http` to `https`.

Take a look at this two questions for more info:
[Can not find where maven local repository path in netbeans 8.0.2 is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834658/can-not-find-where-maven-local-repository-path-in-netbeans-8-0-2-is-set)
[Change Maven repository that NetBeans uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826872/change-maven-repository-that-netbeans-uses?rq=1)
For other info, go through short description in:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My path and java_home was set to open jdk. Switching to oracle jdk fixed it.